# Use strtok() in C

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

```
char* path = (char*)malloc(size); // path = "abc/def/ghi\0"

char** savearr1 // no malloc
char* savearr2[100]; // no malloc
```

this situation, I use strtok(savearr1 or savearr2, "/");

```
/*  if I start this code1 */
while(...) // strtok loop
    strtok(savearr1[i], "/")

/* if I start this code2 */
while(...) // strtok loop
    strtok(savearr2[i], "/")
```

code1 while-loop is segmentation fault,
code2 while-loop is Completed successfully

I have question why code1 is segmentation fault.
Is the behavior char*[] and char** different in strtok?

this is code,

```
int makeFile(const char* fname, FileType type){
    char* path = (char*)malloc(strlen(fname)+1);
    char* fnames[PATH_LEN];

    memcpy(path, fname, strlen(fname));
    path[strlen(fname)] = '\0';
    int num = 0;
    int ino;

    fnames[num++] = strtok(path, "/");
    while(fnames[num++] = strtok(NULL, "/"));

    if(strcmp(fnames[0], "") == 0) return -1;
    if(num == 2){
       makeEntry(pFileSysInfo->rootInodeNum, fnames[0], type);
    }
    else{
        ino = findEntry(pFileSysInfo->rootInodeNum, fnames[0]);
        for(int i=1; i<num-2; i++)
            ino = findEntry(ino, fnames[i]);
        makeEntry(ino, fnames[num-2], type);
    }
    free(path);
}
```

I change char* fnames[PATH_LEN] to char** fnames, occur segmentation falut in `fnames[num++] = strtok(path, "/"); while(fnames[num++] = strtok(NULL, "/"));`

Comment: Show a complete compilable program.

Comment: This depends on how `savearr1` is set, to what it points.

Comment: btw. Just because it doesn't segfault doesn't mean it reliably works

Comment: If I do not change the path, arrsave1 [i] or arrsave2[i] just point to a part of the path, so why does not segmentation falut come up?

Comment: This strictly depends on what you do between the creation of `savearr1` and `savearr2` and the while.

Comment: Use strtok this way
`arrsave[num++] = strtok(path, "/");
while(arrsave[num++] = strtok(NULL, "/"));`

Comment: Please show *all* relevant code. This not a guessing game, isn't  it?

Comment: Also please do not extend your question in comments, but just add updates to the question itself. There is an "edit"-button to it.

Comment: I upload full code. Thanks for the advice

Comment: `savearr2` is an array of pointers. `savearr1` is exactly one pointer, it must be initialized with `malloc` if you want to use it as if it was an array of pointers.

Comment: `char* arr` -> `arr[2]` is third character in arr. `char** savearr1` -> Is not `savearr1[i]` the i-th char* in savearr1?

Comment: `arr[2]` is the third character in `arr`, if and only if `char *arr` points to at least 3 bytes of memory. For example, `char *arr = malloc(3);` or `char buffer[10]; char *arr = buffer;`. Until `arr` points to valid memory, you cannot use it as an array.

Comment: I understand. thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I assume that you never initializate the size of `char** savearr1` so it points to NULL element and when you try to do something with it (like a printf) you get a `segfault` even if the `strtok` doesn't have problem with `NULL` arguments. Here's a code example of what you should do to get it works, it's neither perfect nor complete, just an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
  int size = 5; // size of your path string
  int n = 5; // size of your string array
  char* path =  malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
  sprintf(path,"c/a/");
  char** arr1 = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
  arr1[0] = path;
  int i = 0;
  char* token;
  // iterate over your string array
  for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // take your first string to tokenize
    token = strtok(arr1[i],"/");
    while(token != NULL){
      printf("%s\n",token);
      // keep tokenizing on arr1[i]
      token = strtok(NULL,"/"); 
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to allocate how many `char*` exist in `char**` before I use `char**` variable. Thank you!!

Comment: @이운기 Basically yes, or you have to check if they are not `NULL` when you use them. If this is the correct answer for your question you should mark it as correct answer.